# A way to Highlight <Pressable/> component in react-native?

Tags: react-native

So im using the Pressable Component in react-native instead of using Button because i've heard it has many limitations regarding styling. I've tried using  TouchableHighlight as well but it isnt working porperly for me moreso since my Component already has some styling and Positioning adjusted into it

```js
class randomComponent extends Component {



    render() {
    
    return (
      <Pressable>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </Pressable>
      )
    
    }
```

tl:dr How do i Highlight a Pressable Component? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the "render prop" style instead if you want access to the pressed state without having to store your own `useState` variable.

From [the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#example):

```jsx
<Pressable
  style={({ pressed }) => [
    {
      backgroundColor: pressed
        ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)'
        : 'white'
    },
    styles.wrapperCustom
  ]}>
  {({ pressed }) => (
    <Text style={styles.text}>
      {pressed ? 'Pressed!' : 'Press Me'}
    </Text>
  )}
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
 import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
```

**TouchableOpacity** is better for developers with experience in a web-based background and styling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a state variable to store the `pressed` state and change the component style accordingly

```
class randomComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      
      this.state = {
         pressed: false
      }
    }


    render() {
    
      return (
        <Pressable 
          onPressIn={() => this.setState({pressed: true})} 
          onPressOut={() => this.setState({pressed: false})}
          style={this.state.pressed ? styles.pressed : {}}
        >
          <Text>Hello World</Text>
        </Pressable>
      )
    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pressed: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
})
```